# How compare inside an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numbers, compare

I have this array:

```
array([[4798, 1369, 4139, ..., 2910, 2901,    0],
       [   2, 3161, 1343, ..., 2085, 2065, 2399],
       [ 546,  506,  614, ..., 1874, 1859, 4799],
       [   0,  634, 1341, ..., 1886, 1871, 4799]], dtype=int64)
```

And I can see that there are two equal number (4799) in the last rows. That I want is make a function that compare the adjacent rows and return an array or list with the equal numbers. 
I don't know how to do it. I try do it with a `for` but when I have an largest array this method is very slow.

Comment: Do you want to compare each row with each row? Or just adjacent rows?

Comment: just adjacent rows

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exact problem do you need help with? What is your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say `a` is your array. Then try the following which may help,

```
def equalnumbers(a):
    row,col = np.where((a[1:,:]-a[:-1,:]) ==0)
    return a[row,col]
```

Trial example:

Note the array I use has two numbers that have an equal in their adjacent row. There's also the number 0 twice but in non adjacent rows!

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[4798, 1369, 4139, 2910, 2901, 0],
             [4798, 3161, 1343, 2085, 2065, 2399],
             [546,  506,  614, 1874, 1859, 4799],
             [0,  634, 1341, 1886, 1871, 4799]]) 

equalnumbers(a)
```

Output:

```
array([4798, 4799])
```

The function has only returned the equal numbers from adjacent rows and not the 0 which is present in the non adjacent rows. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I make the following assumptions to answer your question:

- you don't need to detect how often a value is in row A and row B
- you want to compare one row with ONE other row, row for row
- the order of the numbers inside of the both rows you compare doesnt matter (if the order does matter, you should use numpy.equal())

First, use the `set()` function for the both rows you want to compare. Then use the intersection operator `&` on both sets. It returns a new set with elements that are common to both sets [Python Docs - 8.7. sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    # Start at i+1 to prevent double comparison of row pairs
    for j in range(i+1, len(array)):  
        set_a = set(array[i])
        set_b = set(array[j])
        intersection = set_a & set_b
```